# EventStore and EventMetadata in .net 6

Tags: .net, event-sourcing, eventstoredb

When I append events to the eventstream log I'm using
...

```
var myEvents = events.Select(@event => new EventData(
            Guid.NewGuid(),
            @event.GetType().Name,
            true,
            Serialize(@event),
            null //metadata
        )).ToArray();

return connection.AppendToStreamAsync(streamName, version, myEvents);
```

Below is an example how I deserialize the event when I retrieve the event from the store, this will not work because I cannot deserialize it without metadata (which I struggle to insert, it's null cause I don't know how to insert it).

I have an extension method for deserializing ResolvedEvent from EventStore.ClientAPI.

```
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader
public static class EventDeserializer
{
   public static object Deserialize(this ResolvedEvent resolvedEvent)
   {
      var meta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventMetadata>
                   (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resolvedEvent.Event.Metadata));
      var dataType = Type.GetType(meta.GetType().ToString());
      var jsonData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resolvedEvent.Event.Data);

      return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData, dataType);
   }
}
```

if matters I'm using `.net 6` and `EventStore.Client 5.0.12`.
Just for the info, I'm able to insert the event in the store (without metadata). The issue here is when I load the event and trying to deseralize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metadata is just a JSON object. You can serialize it the same way you do it with the event data.

I am not sure why you use the `EventMetadata` type from `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader` as it has nothing to do with the EventStoreDB client.

You don't necessarily need to store the event type in metadata as it's already in the resolved event, the `EventType` property of type `string`.

If you don't need event meta, you can avoid reading it. If you need the reading function to work with `null` meta, you can check for `null`.